# Странное поведение при подключении классов Js

Tags: javascript, css, less

Задача сделать игру Simon, при написании наткнулся на баг, что не могут быть нажата одна и та же кнопка подряд,(т.е  если выпадает рандомом 1,3,3 то третья 1 раз только анимацию сыграет не могу понять в какую сторону идти: less:

```
.ani-proporses(@color){
    0%{background-color:@color;}
    50%{background-color:darken(@color,20%);}
    100%{background-color:@color;}
}
.animate(@animation-name){
    animation-name: @animation-name;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

Js:

```
var block1 = document.querySelector(".block1");
var block2 = document.querySelector(".block2");
var block3 = document.querySelector(".block3");
var block4 = document.querySelector(".block4");
var numberOfClicks = 3;
var globalTiming = 1000;
var animationDelay = 1500;
var mass = [block1,block2,block3,block4];
function startGame() {
var crutch = getRandomInt(1,5); 
var randomNumber = getRandomInt(1,5);
var checkNumber = 0;
console.log("Игра началась");
for(var i = 1; i<=numberOfClicks;i++){
    var randomNumber = getRandomInt(1,5);
    console.log("randomNumber = " +randomNumber + "checkNumber = "+ checkNumber );
        while(checkNumber === randomNumber)
        {
            randomNumber = getRandomInt(1,5);
        }

    switch (randomNumber) {
  case 1:
    setTimeout(amimationGo1, globalTiming);

    globalTiming+=animationDelay;

    console.log(1);
    break;
  case 2:
    setTimeout(amimationGo2, globalTiming);     
    globalTiming+=animationDelay;
    removeAnimation();    
    console.log(2);
    break;
  case 3:
    setTimeout(amimationGo3, globalTiming);
    globalTiming+=animationDelay;
    removeAnimation();
    console.log(3);
    break;
  case 4:
    setTimeout(amimationGo4, globalTiming);
    globalTiming+=animationDelay;
    removeAnimation();    
    console.log(4);
    break;
}
checkNumber = randomNumber;
}
}   


//переделать
function removeAnimation() {
    block1.classList.remove("animate-1");
    block2.classList.remove("animate-2");
    block3.classList.remove("animate-3");
    block4.classList.remove("animate-4");
}
function amimationGo1() {
    block1.classList.add("animate-1");
}
function amimationGo2() {
    block2.classList.add("animate-2");
}
function amimationGo3() {
    block3.classList.add("animate-3");
}
function amimationGo4() {
    block4.classList.add("animate-4");
}



function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

решил добавлением

```
function amimationGo1() {
    block1.classList.add("animate-1");
     setTimeout(removeAnimation,1000);
}
```